# Replaced List<T> object not persisting consistently in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I have a `List<Workout>` object that occasionally needs to be sorted (e.g., if a user adds a Workout out of order), but I can't seem to get the new sorted `List<Workout>` to persist.  My code works the moment it runs (i.e., it shows up on the view as sorted), but when I exit the ViewController or restart the app, I see nothing.  The nothing is due to the `exercise.workoutDiary.removeAll()` persisting, but apparently the subsequent assignment to the `exercise.workoutDiary = sortedWorkoutDiary` is not persisting.  Any ideas why?

Everything else works just fine.  The typical `recordWorkout()` case works assuming nothing is entered out of order. So the persisting is working in nearly all cases except for this overwrite of the sorted List.

The update happens here:

```
struct ExerciseDetailViewModel {

    private let exercise: Exercise!

    func recordWorkout(newWorkout: Workout) {
        let lastWorkout = exercise.workoutDiary.last // grab the last workout for later comparison

        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            exercise.workoutDiary.append(newWorkout) // write the workout no matter what
        }

        if let secondToLastWorkout = lastWorkout { // only bother checking out of order if there is a last workout...
            if newWorkout.date < secondToLastWorkout.date { // ...and now look to see if they are out of order
                let sortedWorkoutDiary = exercise.sortedWorkouts
                try! realm.write {
                    exercise.workoutDiary.removeAll()
                    exercise.workoutDiary = sortedWorkoutDiary
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

final class Exercise: Object {

    var workoutDiary = List<Workout>()
    var sortedWorkouts: List<Workout> {
        return List(workoutDiary.sorted("date"))
    }
}

final class Workout: Object {

    dynamic var date = NSDate()
    var sets = List<WorkSet>()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List<T>` properties in Realm Swift must be mutated in place, not assigned to. The Swift runtime does not provide any way for Realm to intercept assignments to properties of generic types. Instead, you should use methods like [`appendContentsOf(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_RangeReplaceableCollectionType_Protocol/) to mutate the `List<T>`:

```
exercise.workoutDiary.removeAll()
exercise.workoutDiary.appendContentsOf(sortedWorkoutDiary)
```

This limitation on assignment to properties of generic types is why the Realm Swift documentation [recommends that you declare such properties using `let` rather than `var`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#cheatsheet). This will allow the Swift compiler to catch these sorts of mistakes.

One further note: for your `sortedWorkouts` computed property, it'd be preferable for it to return `Results<Workout>` instead to avoid allocating and populating an intermediate `List<Workout>`.

Comment: This makes sense.  I changed my code to use appendContentsOf(_:) and its working now.  I also tried switching the sortedWorkouts computed property type to Results<Workout> and it did not work.  Nothing saved in that case.  Type List<Workout> still works fine.