# Realm List not updating in database - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-list

I have a model that writes data to Realm on one view controller.  and then a few view controllers later, pulls that model back out and fills in the rest of the data in my model.  Everything updates to the database correctly except for a List.  It always states that there are 0 entries in the database.

what i'm doing is I have another model object gathering data called `challengeModeGameData.answerCollection`  It's a collection of `UserData` objects which hold user answers as well as correct answers.

When I pull the previously written object back out, `GameDataObject`, I can access all the properties and set them with values from `ChallengeModeGameData`.  One property I set is:

`gameDataObject.answerCollection = challengeModeGameData.answerCollection`

A print to the console shows me the data is there, by that, `gameDataObject.answerCollection` does indeed hold the values I want it to.  But when the `write` transaction is completed, all of my other values that I set from the `ChallengeModeObject` are there, but the database still claims it has zero objects in it for my `answerCollection`.

Is there anything different I'm supposed to do for Realm Lists (I know they aren't dynamic) that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you share the definition of the classes involved in this example?

Comment: so if anyone runs into this issue, @bdash helped me solve it...see here:

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4740

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replaced List<T> object not persisting consistently in Realm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557872/replaced-listt-object-not-persisting-consistently-in-realm)